# Correctly use takeUntil() for stopping observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, observer-pattern, rxjs5

I'm trying to create 2 observables, that basically do inverse operations. It's a service discovery endpoint, so when starting an application it has to try registering to the service discovery until success. So I thought of creating an observable like this:

```
const create$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next('Trying to create observation');
    sp.put(endpoint, { json: true }, (err, res, payload) => {
      err ? observer.error(err) : observer.complete();
    });
  });
```

And when the application is doing graceful shutdown, I want to do the inverse operation. Like this:

```
const delete$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    console.log('deleted subscribed');
    observer.next('Trying to delete observation');
    sp.delete(endpoint, { json: true }, (err, res, payload) => {
      err ? observer.error(err) : observer.complete();
    });
  });
```

So I decided to create a function that returns an object that has a `.create()` and `.delete()`. The problem I want to solve is that when the application is up and trying to register, but unable to reach the service discovery endpoint and later the application initiates it's graceful shutdown process and invokes the `.delete()` operation then the `.create()` operation should not run anymore.

```
function observe({ url, version, serviceName }) {
  const endpoint = `/endpoint/${serviceName}/${version}/${encodeURIComponent(url)}`;

  const create$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next('Trying to create observation');
    sp.put(endpoint, { json: true }, (err, res, payload) => {
      err ? observer.error(err) : observer.complete();
    });
  });

  const delete$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    console.log('deleted subscribed');
    observer.next('Trying to delete observation');
    sp.delete(endpoint, { json: true }, (err, res, payload) => {
      err ? observer.error(err) : observer.complete();
    });
  });

  return {
    create() {
      return create$.retry(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY).takeUntil(delete$); // This is where I would want to takeUntil()
    },
    delete({ interval = 5000, times = 0 } = {}) {
      return delete$.retry(times);
    },
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when using `.takeUntil()` it subscribes to the `delete$` which starts doing the delete operation which has the effect of stopping the `create$` observable instantly.

I tried doing `takeUntil(Observable.merge(Observable.never(), delete$))` but it subscribes to both so doesn't work. I also tried doing `takeUntil(Observable.concat(Observable.never(), delete$))` the first one never ends (:P) and the second one is never subscribed.

Comment: Is your retry logic on the right one? The description made it sound like the "create" is the one that retries?

Comment: @jayphelps I updated the retry logic on the create. I want to repeat indefinitely on create, but stop if delete started trying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most Observables are **cold** and **unicast**. This is a bit of a lengthy topic, so I'll defer to the great article [Hot vs Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) for the most part, but to sum it up:

> #### COLD is when your observable creates the producer
>
> ```
> // COLD
> var cold = new Observable((observer) => {
>   var producer = new Producer();
>   // have observer listen to producer here
> });
> ```
>
> #### HOT is when your observable closes over the producer
>
> ```
> // HOT
> var producer = new Producer();
> var hot = new Observable((observer) => {
>   // have observer listen to producer here
> });
> ```

In your example this is a critical distinction because both `create$` and `delete$` are cold. So as you found, providing `delete$` to the `takeUntil` causes `delete$` to be subscribed to, kicking off the request.

If you want to keep the structure/API of your code as-is, one way to accomplish this is by using a Subject that is treated as a sort of "notifier". Subjects are multicast and "hot" (even though they don't do anything by themselves).

```
function observe({ url, version, serviceName }) {
  // etc...

  const shutdown$ = new Subject(); // <---------------- create our notifier

  return {
    create() {
      return create$
        .retry(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
        .takeUntil(shutdown$); // <-------------------- take our notifier
    },
    delete({ interval = 5000, times = 0 } = {}) {
      return Observable.defer(() => {
        shutdown$.next(); // <------------------------- notify
        return delete$.retry(times);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

We used `Observable.defer()` so that we can perform that `shutdown$.next()` side effect whenever someone actually subscribes to the Observable we return.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

You can use Observable in `.takeUntill` without actually subscribing to it by creating intermediate `Subject`. Then you can subscribe to that subject instead of the original. Something like this:

```
const delete$ = new Subject();
...
create() {
  return create$
    .takeUntill(delete$);   
},
delete() {
  create(...).subscribe(delete$);
  return delete;
}
```

**Approach #2**

However in your case I think it would be better to create subject, which will notify when `.delete` is called. Like this:

```
const onDelete$ = new Subject();
...
create() {
  return create$
    .takeUntill(onDelete$); 
},
delete() {
  onDelete$.next();
  return ...
}
```